# Xcode build variables for iOS or Mac for carthage support

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, frameworks, carthage

## Overview

I am working on developing multiple cascading set of Dynamic Frameworks that are integrated by **Carthage**.  I'm trying to adapt the principals in this [blog post](http://colemancda.github.io/programming/2015/02/11/universal-ios-osx-framework/) and the WWDC video [Sharing code between iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#233)

### My Situation:

I have 3 Dynamic frameworks who included each other in a cascading format:

Dynamic Framework: **DataManager** includes Dynamic Framework: **GDL90** includes DynamicFramework: **EGL96**.

#### Work thus far...

The jist of what I'm doing is taking a single target and having it configured to build frameworks for both iOS and Mac [explained here](http://colemancda.github.io/programming/2015/02/11/universal-ios-osx-framework/)

- Base SDK: OSX
- Supported Platforms: `machos iphoneos iphonesimucator`
- Valid Architectures: `arm64 armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64`

And then under your test targets you change the search paths:

- Runpath Search Paths: `$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks @executable_path/../Frameworks @loader_path/../Frameworks`
- Framework Search Paths: `$(SDKROOT) $(inherited)`

#### Where the problem starts

I configured the **EGM96** project as such to build multiple build for multiple targets.  This works nicely and compiles fine.  Where the trouble starts is once we get carthage involved.

In my **GDL90** project I included **EGM96** from carthage

After I run `carthage update` I end up with the following files:

- `./Carthage/Build/Mac/EGM96.framework`
- `./Carthage/Build/iOS/EGM96.framework`

I've also configured the **GDL90** project to do a multi-platform build, but thats where the error starts.  I'm unable to dynamically configure the build process (thus far) to pull in the correct framework version based on the correct target (i.e. OS X build pulls from `/Carthage/Build/Mac/EGM96.framework`).

I've spent some time looking through the [build variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW60) for Xcode and I have yet to find a working solution.

The caveat is as these were initially `iOS` projects i had linked in the `iOS` framework into Xcode and thus I end up with the entirely appropriate error:

`ld: building for OSX, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/jstein/devel/DigitalCopilot/GDL90/Carthage/Build/iOS/EGM96.framework/EGM96' for architecture x86_64`

Is there an **easy** solution to some hidden build variables I'm missing that would allow at compile time Xcode to pull the framework from the appropriate carthage build path?